# ngIf for display different table details

Tags: html, angular, frontend, angular-ng-if

I have a table that presents data - but I want to display a "table has no data" message within the table if the data is empty.

Here is the code for the table:

```
<table id="productTable">
          <thead>
            <tr class="header-group">
              <th>Product number</th>
              <th>Product ID</th>
              <th>USERNAME</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody *ngFor="let productDetail of productDetailResponse">
          <div *ngIf="productDetailResponse.length > 0 ; else noDetails">
          <tr>
              <td>{{ productDetail.productNo }}</td>
              <td>{{ tradeDetail.productId }}</td>
              <td>{{ tradeDetail.userName }}</td>
            </tr>
          <tr #noDetails>
            <td> Table has no data </td>
          </tr>
          </div>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

What I tried to do was write the if statement for 1 table row to be displayed if my array.length is greater than 0 and if it is not greater than 0, display the table row with "#noDetails" - but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: why we are looping on `<tbody` ? it should loop on `<tr` or `<td`.

Comment: yeah ur correct

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use `ng-template`:

```
<table id="productTable">
   <thead>
      <tr class="header-group">
         <th>Product number</th>
         <th>Product ID</th>
         <th>USERNAME</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let productDetail of productDetailResponse">
         <ng-container *ngIf="productDetailResponse.length ; else noDetails">
            <td>{{ productDetail.productNo }}</td>
            <td>{{ tradeDetail.productId }}</td>
            <td>{{ tradeDetail.userName }}</td>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-template #noDetails>
            <td> Table has no data </td>
         </ng-template>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```